# CSS specific for Safari

Tags: css, safari

How do you target specifically safari in css with styles?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69440/what-safari-specific-pure-css-hacks-are-out-there

Answer (score 1):

Safari Stokely Hack: http://www.stormdetector.com/hacks/safarihack.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://themechanism.com/blog/2008/01/08/safari-css-hack-redux/

I used this for a webapp I was working on - worked for me and still working with the recent safari update (5.1?)

Also the other browsers were not affected.