# Apply CSS only for Safari?

Tags: css, safari

Is it possible to add a block of css that I only want to be displayed in Safari and no other browsers?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052218/is-there-any-equivalent-to-ie-conditional-comment-for-chrome-and-safari

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's an example which would set the font colour of your site to green if your browser is Safari or Chrome (both share the common Webkit rendering engine).

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    body {
        color:green; /* on Safari and Chrome  */
    }
}
```

This is taken from another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69440/what-safari-specific-pure-css-hacks-are-out-there)

Comment: I assume you meant Chrome, not Opera. Chrome uses the WebKit engine, Opera uses their own engine (called Presto).

Comment: @jhurshman, yes I did, thanks (it's getting late on a Friday :-) )

Comment: @jhursh it targets Opera 9.2 too

Comment: how can i further add a media query to this safari specific css??

Answer (score 0):

Using the UserAgent string, you can check for Safari and !Chrome. Both use the WebKit Renderer and both have Safari in the UA string, but Chrome also has 'Chrome'. To be honest, I'd just check for Webkit and code to that because who knows what other WebKit browser put in their UA strings.

Safari :

`Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; zh-HK) AppleWebKit/533.18.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.2 Safari/533.18.5`

Chrome :

`Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US) AppleWebKit/540.0 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu/10.10 Chrome/8.1.0.0 Safari/540.0`

Comment: The UserAgent string can be spoofed very easily. This is not a reliable approach.

Comment: I'm not saying its the best method, but to find SAFARI ONLY is nigh impossible so you take what you can get.

Comment: does css use the useragent to check which browser?

Comment: No, I think you would have to use a JS check in your code and include the appropriate style sheet.

Comment: user agent can be spoofed, but 99.99999% of the people browsing the web won't be spoofing user agents to get around minor css hacks so its generally safe if its a last resort.

Comment: why would someone spoof the user UserAgent string, and if you do spoof it you should expect some irregularities to ensue. UserAgent away my friend

Answer (score -2):

Use this. It will work only in Safari.

```
/* Only for Safari  */
::i-block-chrome, .yourClassName {
     border:1px solid #f00;
}
```