# Safari specific css

Tags: css, safari

How to write only safari specific styles without affecting any other browser styles?

I have tried it but it is not working in safari.I'm using Safari 5+.

```
@media not all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
  .btn-group > .btn + .btn {

      margin-left: -8px;
  }  
  .btn-group:hover a {
      z-index:1;
  }
  .btn-group:hover button{
      z-index:10;
  }
  .input-append input{
      z-index:1;
  }
  .input-append  a{
      z-index:10;
  }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4053930/apply-css-only-for-safari

Answer (score 0):

Try thi site:
http://www.browserhacks.com/#sa

`html[xmlns*=""]:root .selector  {}` should work..

so, for the first rule, try following.

```
html[xmlns*=""]:root .btn-group > .btn + .btn {
  margin-left: -8px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Its work perfectly on the Safari browser only

Only for Safari ::i-block-chrome, #your id or class name{
}

Comment: Could you explain it better? Maybe providing a minimal working example?

Comment: Here's an example which would set the font color of your site to red if your browser is Safari 

<div class="media-list">
<ul>
   <li>abc text</li>  
</ul>

</div>
::i-block-chrome,  .media-list > li{ 
 color: red;
}