# Determine Safari browser in skin file?

Tags: c#, .net, css, dotnetnuke, skinning

i'm working in a dnn6 portal and use this code in my skinpage.ascx. but it does not load the SafariSkin.css.

```
     <!--[if Safari]>
     <link href="SafariSkin.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
     <![endif]-->

     <!--[if !Safari]>
     <link href="Skin.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
     <![endif]-->
```

but if i change the condition to "IE" it works. WHY?

i also use the following code in:

```
     <dnn:STYLES runat="server" ID="Stylesnotsafari" Name="notsafari" StyleSheet="SafariSkin.css" Condition="Safari" UseSkinPath="true"/>
```

and again just when the condition is IE it works properly.
Any Idea??

what should i do to have "safari" condition???

Comment: Hold on please I Test

Comment: Conditional Comments are exclusive to Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're in ascx file you can use server code to determine the browser.

```
<link href="<%= Request.Browser.Browser == "Safari" ? "SafariSkin.css" : "NotSafari.css" %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

For this to work, make sure the language of the skin is C# (first line, where it says language="vb", change to language="c#"), or modify the code to above to VB.net.

Also, for older version of .NET the Safari browser is not correctly identified. If that's the case, read more, for example at http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t119465-asp-net-2-0-vs-safari-browser.html to update the browser detection manually.

Answer (score 0):

Safari cannot be targeted in the same way that IE can through conditionals.

There are some [hacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69440/what-safari-specific-pure-css-hacks-are-out-there) that may work within your standard stylesheet, but really you would be best served by adjusting your html/css in a way that will support Safari (a task which is typically far less labor-intensive than it is in IE).